# Equivalent of x++ in Lua?

Tags: lua, operators, roblox

I am trying to do

```lua
local a = 1
for i,v in pairs(getloadedmodules()) do
 if v:IsA("ModuleScript") then
  v.Name = a = a + 1
 end
end
```

But obviously that doesn't work because of the = sign after a. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Break it into 2 assignments.

Answer (score 4):

```lua
local a = 1
for i,v in pairs(getloadedmodules()) do
 if v:IsA("ModuleScript") then
  a = a + 1
  v.Name = a
 end
end
```